# Including NodeJS library manually not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to include a NodeJS library manually for our config, and I downloaded this library: https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/

and I tried to include the library with

```
var amqp = require("amqp.node-master");
```

I ended up getting exceptions for

```
Cannot find module './defs'
```

I look in connection.js and it has this at the beginning:

```
'use strict';

var defs = require('./defs');
var constants = defs.constants;
var frame = require('./frame');
var HEARTBEAT = frame.HEARTBEAT;
var Mux = require('./mux').Mux;
```

Looking at it, I don't see any defs folder or def.js in the library. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is `amqp.node-master` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at their source, you'll see that [def.js is generated during build](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/Makefile).

That means you can't install it directly from GitHub; you need to install a version that ran `make`.

Comment: so if I run the makefile then I can use that build?